# Need to figure a way to launch an app without specifying the full path to the binary

Tags: python, path, windows-8.1

I am writing an automation test with python and need to figure a way to launch an app without specifying the full path to the binary. 
Sys specs: 
Windows 8.1, 
Python 2.7.

Comment: Is the information stored anywhere else, like in the registry? Or do you expect to search through all the binaries in 'Program Files', for example?

Comment: `python my_app.py` assuming you are running it from the directory where my_app.py is ...

Comment: There's a path in registry, yes. Originally I wanted it to search through all the binaries in "Program Files", but now I'll go with whatever. What I am trying to launch is the electron .exe that resides somewhere in PF and I don't want my test to depend on the full path to the binary.